# Make ReSharper let me insert tab after 'else' by tab key

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, resharper

Currently, if I have

```cs
if(thing)
    dostuff;
else
```

and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> after the `else`, ReSharper forces a newline

```cs
if(thing)
    dostuff;
else
{
}
```

whereas what I want is to insert a tab character like what the <kbd>tab</kbd> key should do, as I often like having comments after `if`/`else` and prefer them to be tab-aligned

```cs
if(thing)     //etc
    dostuff;
else          //etc
{
}
```

I've turned off both Braces and Parentheses options in

Environment->Editor->Editor Behaviour

as well as unchecking "else" in the Templates Explorer.

Are there more options elsewhere I can access dealing with this? Is there some way to make ReSharper just plain never, ever, ever add braces, newlines or parenthesis without me telling it to? And generally allow me to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key like I would were it not installed?

Answer (score 0):

The option should be located within the menu:

ReSharper -> Options... -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping.

Within this "**Line Breaks and Wrapping**" list of settings:

Place on New Line -> Place "else" on new line (*with a check box*)

Here, you should be able to find and uncheck other situations where you want to remove ReSharper's ability to add new lines and/or brackets when you do things.